# How to create a same dropdown menu for different labels?

Tags: python, csv, flask, jinja2

I am building an application in Flask which takes data from different CSV files. I have different labels ( Column names in the CSV file) and for each label I have the same drop-down menu. For example-

1. Mode of Transport

   - Multiple Choice
   - Single Choice
   - Temporal
2. Timestamp

   - Multiple Choice
   - Single Choice
   - Temporal

Firstly, I tried creating this template. This is my code-

```
<div class="container">
<form class="col s12" action="/config" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Assign Fieldnames</h2>
            {% for x in title %}
              <label> {{ x }} :</label>
              <select name="choice">
                     <option value="">Select One</option>
                     <option value="time">Temporal</option>
                     <option value="single">Single Choice</option>
                     <option value="multiple">Multiple Choice</option>
              </select>
            {% endfor %}
        <input type="hidden" name="filename" value= {{filename}}></input>
          <button class="btn" type="submit" value="Update">Submit</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

**View**

```
def config():
    filepath = request.form['filename']
    choice_to_make = ['Select one', 'Temporal', 'Single-Choice''Multi-
Choice']
    print(filepath)
    with open(filepath,'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        title = next(reader)
        print(title)
    return render_template('pages/placeholder.configure1.html',
                           title=title,choice_to_make= choice_to_make, 
filename=filepath)
```

Secondly, I am not able to figure out how to save these choices( Multiple choice, Single Choice and Temporal) for each label so that I can query the data on the basis of these choices after sending this CSV to Mongodb.

Comment: Could you include the code for the `/config` route?

Comment: @LuisOrduz I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to match each label *select option* to a unique specific name, to be able to associate them in the following view.

**Template**

You can use the index of the loop to do so.

```
{% for name in title %}
  <label> {{ name }} :</label>
  <select name="choice-{{ loop.index }}">
         <option disabled selected value> Select One</option>
         <option value="time">Temporal</option>
         <option value="single">Single Choice</option>
         <option value="multiple">Multiple Choice</option>
  </select><br>
{% endfor %}
```

**View**

Next step, in the view, you can store the choices given by the form in a dictionary or in a list of tuples (see the second suggestion). What matters is to take a structure that allows to keep an easy match between titles and choices.

The dictionary is more interesting if you want to call specific titles next:

```
@app.route("/config", methods=['POST'])
def config():

    choices = {}
    with open(request.form['filename'], 'r') as csvfile :
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        titles = next(reader)
        for index, title in enumerate(titles,1):
            choice = 'choice-' + str(index)
            choices[title] = request.form.get(choice)

    #choices = {'Mode of Transport': 'time', 'Timestamp':'multiple' }
```

---

The list may be better to process all titles in a row and keep the order:

```
    choices = []
    with open(request.form['filename'], 'r') as csvfile :
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        titles = next(reader)
        for index, title in enumerate(titles,1):
            choice = 'choice-' + str(index)
            choices.append((title, request.form.get(choice))

    #choices = [('Mode of Transport','time'), ('Timestamp','multiple')]
```

Comment: Can you explain me this line `for index, title in enumerate(titles, 1):` ?

Comment: `enumerate` returns a tuple with an index and the associated value, by adding `1` in the arguments, it makes the index start at 1 instead of 0. Then `for index, title` is the syntax to unpack the returned tuple and associate a name to the values

Comment: this does not seem to work. Is there any way to loop by using the number of fields?

Comment: I am able to get the label names but drop down does not works.Could you tell me where am i getting wrong?

Comment: this approach is based on the fields given by the header of the csv file, it should be the same used to populate the html template. Maybe i missed something ? What doesn't work with dropdown exactly ?

Comment: it only shows the first "select one" in the menu and menu does not drop down, but when i inspect the element, it populates with all the option but does not appear.

Comment: looks like the `select` is disabled, did you add the parameters with `disabled` i suggest in the code ? make sure it's applied to the option `"Select one"` and not to the `select` tag. (otherwise try without these parameters)

Comment: I tried removing the "select one" option, then also the same problem. It will show latitude in the menu and menu will not drop down.

Comment: Please could you send the code you are using for the template ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save only one choice per label. The one you will receive in your `POST` request. These values will be available in the `request.form` that is MultiDict type, and they are the only *valid* values, you should store in your database. You can access them via the `request.form` object.

From your HTML form, it looks like you will receive only one other item in the `request.form` - 'choice', and it will have two values. So you will have to solve how to distinguish among them which of two values should be associated with the 'Mode of Transport' and 'Timestamp'. I'm skeptical they will appear in the same order as on the form, so I would prefer to provide different names inside the `name` attribute of the `select` tag.

Unfortunately, you didn't indicate what `title` is, so it looks like you should use either loop to go through the `request.form` object and associate your variables with received values, or hardcode them in some way.